# How to check whether any ItemListener is added to Hazelcast IQueue or not

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

From instance A, I have created one `q1`(`IQueue`) also added `ItemListener` to it. Now from Instace B I need to check, is there any ItemListener added to the same queue. If not then needs to added.

**So programatically how can we check whether ItemListener added to `IQueue` or not ?**

> Updated with usecase

In our Ecommerce site we are usign this for flashsale

`When admin configure an item for flashsale` : we will create queue(`IQueue`) for that item also bind one ItemListener to it

`item Queue role`:- When user buy n quantity of that item, we will add n number of flag to that queue.

`ItemListener role` :- on itemAdded we will compare available stock and size of queue, make item out of stock if queue size is reached to available stock.

`goal :-` There should be a single `ItemListener` for particuler item acrross the application nodes

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you want to guarantee only one listener to be added to a queue. Why not use the oldest member (the privileged cluster member) to register the listener? Do you need any kind of simple load balancing?import

```
import com.hazelcast.core.*;
import java.util.UUID;

public class OneListenerPerQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Hazelcast instance
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        // Add a basic distributed object listener
        hz.addDistributedObjectListener(new QueueListener(hz));

        // Create 100 unique queues
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String uniqueQueue = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            hz.getQueue(uniqueQueue);
        }
    }

    private static class QueueListener
            implements DistributedObjectListener {

        private final PartitionService partitionService;

        private QueueListener(HazelcastInstance hz) {
            this.partitionService = hz.getPartitionService();
        }

        public void distributedObjectCreated(DistributedObjectEvent distributedObjectEvent) {
            // DistirbutedObject from the event
            DistributedObject distObj = distributedObjectEvent.getDistributedObject();

            // If queue ask PartitionService if the name is assigned to the local member
            if (distObj instanceof IQueue) {
                Partition partition = partitionService.getPartition(distObj.getName());
                if (partition.getOwner().localMember()) {
                    // If local than add our ItemListener
                    ((IQueue) distObj).addItemListener(new MyItemListener(), true);
                }
            }
        }

        public void distributedObjectDestroyed(DistributedObjectEvent distributedObjectEvent) {
        }
    }

    private static class MyItemListener implements ItemListener<String> {

        public void itemAdded(ItemEvent<String> itemEvent) {
            System.out.println(itemEvent);
        }

        public void itemRemoved(ItemEvent<String> itemEvent) {
            System.out.println(itemEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use an atomic putIfAbsent on IMap to register yourself as the owner of the queue or using an ILock with tryLock. In both cases you need to be aware of the fact that if the "handling node" dies somebody has to take over.

Comment: is `ItemListener` binded on Hazelcast client instead of server ? It is easier for me if i find some workaround to check listener is exsist or not

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but maybe I did :) So if a client registers a listener, the listener is executed at the client but the listener interest is registered at one of the server nodes.

Comment: `@noctarius` - How can I achive `Only one Itemlistner to queue` accross the all aplication node. Detail answer would be appricated!

Comment: @U2Answer I've added an example anyhow this will only work in a stable cluster, whenever a member goes you have to figure out the assignments and reassign the "lost queues" to a new node. As partitions are also reassigned you could just remove all listeners and assign all of them again (by retrieving all DisitributedObjects and applying the same logic as above). I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Noctarius, But where we need to add above code to cofigure `DistributedObjectListener` (QueueListener), which basically take cares of adding one listner to each `newly created queue`. If I include above code in my project then it will aging present in all server nodes, so again we face the same problem by having mulitple listener. Is there any way to configure the same by `xml` file at `hazelcast server`.

Comment: No you won't have multiple listeners as only the "owner" of the queue (the one that would take the key with the same name) will register a listener. That means each queue has only one listener but different queues will have different listening nodes.